# Link to a line in a QTextBrowser

Tags: qt, qplaintextedit, qtextbrowser

I'm trying to make an advanced find system. What i'm trying to do is to display in a QTextBrowser the line where the string that you're searching for and make it clickable. And for when you click it, it redirects you to that line.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use html anchor (`<a href="...">`) and connect to signal anchorClicked of QTextBrowser